# How to view configuration Lync 2013 - Impossible?

Tags: microsoft-office, windows-server-2003, lync

I was wondering if there is a way to view the automatically configured connection settings? Basically, I'm just trying to figure out which servers are being connected to on my windows laptop so that I set the lync client connection settings up manually on my mac.

Also, I've tried sniffing the network traffic to try and figure out which servers are being used, but to no avail.

Comment: Are you asking how to figure out your Lync Server address so you can get Mac Lync up and running?

Comment: Yup yup. Also, sorry for the delay in response!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get the Windows Lync client's configuration info by control-clicking the Lync icon in the system tray as described in this article:  [How can I check my Lync 2010 configuration?](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/communicator-help/troubleshooting-sign-in-issues-HA101859258.aspx#_How_can_I_1)

Comment: Thank you. This was exactly what I needed. Same scenario, use Lync on mac instead of Windows. Great!